# Selenium ide (Firefox) is giving error in feature of deleting a record from list

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium ide (Firefox addon) to make Test Cases of Web Application.
When I click on Delete icon in a list of records, a javascript conformation message appear. selenium Display error in running a click on Delete icon.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Element //a[@onclick='javascript:DeleteCategoryMaster(480,this);'] not Found

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not support popup window handling. For this u have to add extra lines in the generated script.